# I am applying for a UK Visitor Visa. Can I plan to give birth in an NHS hospital (paying for it), or must I deliver in a fully private hospital?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have been with my British citizen partner for 5 years, we successfully obtained a UK Visitor Visa in 2020 to meet his family, we are now applying for another UK Visitor Visa, to spend 5.5 months with his family during my maternity leave, during which I will deliver our son. We live in Ethiopia together, my partner has lived in Ethiopia for 10 years, he works fully remotely.

The Medical Visitor Visa [permits](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/visit-for-medical-reasons):

> private medical treatment at a hospital or other medical facility
>
> treatment at an NHS hospital, as long as the care is paid for by your own government under a reciprocal healthcare arrangement

I am unable to determine whether this means we should make arrangements to deliver in a fully private hospital, or whether delivering in an NHS hospital, and paying the charges ourselves, is permitted, due to our application being for a standard Visitor Visa on the basis of family in the UK.

In our application we have shown cost estimates and adequate funds for either. An NHS hospital would be closer to where we will be staying and his family, but we are unable to find a clear answer on whether this qualifies as 'private' for the Visitor Visa.

Comment: There is an answer here https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/22646/i-am-applying-for-a-uk-visitor-visa-can-i-plan-to-give-birth-in-an-nhs-hospital/22648?noredirect=1#comment37813_22648 - this question was erroneously migrated there, then back again to here.

Comment: The visa application was rejected because we did not provide a letter from a doctor stating the location, cost and duration of delivery. I am not sure whether it needs to be a letter from a non-NHS institution.